# How to interpret + and - precisions and recalls?

Tags: classification, python, precision-recall, accuracy, precision

I understand the general calculation and concept of precision and recall. But when I am trying to predict people's ethnicity using some feature, say for example, predicting a binary class Chinese vs non-Chinese. I get a pair of precisions and a pair of recalls from python.

For example:

```
                     (Gold standard)
                   Chinese  non-Chinese
 (Predicted) Chinese    A         B
         non-Chinese    C         D
```

Results

```
Accuracy    0.9967
Precision + 0.4808
Precision - 0.999
Recall +    0.7095
Recall -    0.9976
```

I don't understand what the positive and negative classifications mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precision and recall both examine your system's performance on a specific class--typically the positive one. For example, recall can be computed as:
$$Recall = \frac{\textrm{True Positives}}{\textrm{True Positives} + \textrm{False Negatives}}$$Similarly , precision can be calculated as 
$$Precision = \frac{\textrm{True Positives}}{\textrm{True Positives + False Positives}}$$

In both cases, only one class--the positive class--shows up in the numerator. Your code appears to be computing precision/recall twice, once for the positive class (Chinese) and once for the negative class (non-Chinese).

If you set Chinese as the positive class, you'll get the following:
$$\begin{align} 
Recall_+ &= \frac{A}{A+C}\\
Precision_+ &= \frac{A}{A+B} \\
Recall_- &= \frac{D}{B+D} \\
Precision_- &= \frac{D}{C+D}
\end{align}
$$

This isn't exactly *wrong*, but it strikes me as a little unusual. Precision and recall are great metrics when you care about identifying one type of something in the middle of a sea of distracting and irrelevant stuff. If you're interested in the system's performance on both classes, another measure (e.g., aROC) might be better.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused about what the + and - means. Say I define "Chinese" as the positive, then the recall + will be A/(A+B), correct? And if I define "non-Chinese" as negative, will the recall - be D/(C+D)? And isn't D/(C+D) just the same as precision +?

Comment: Sorry--I made a few stupid mistakes in the first version (wrote recall where I meant precision). I hope this clears it up. 

In general, recall_ is not going to be equal to precision+ or anything like that though....